# Google pie chart (any chart) not working inside an ASP.Net AJAX Update Panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, google-visualization, updatepanel

I am facing problem with Google pie chart and Update panel. 
There is one Tab container inside a update panel which has two Tab panels. 
Each tab panel contains div and script to plot Google pie chart. 
when first time page gets load, tab1 works properly. 
but if i click on next tab then both the tab doesn't plot pie chart.
i have used "Sys.Application.add_load(methodname) inside each tab panel. 
i have used script which is in Google play. Thanks in Advance.

Here is the code (set as image as I could not get the editor to show the HTML)
[image]

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide code to replicate the problem.

Comment: And what's up with a different account posting the code for the question?

Comment: @MoizTankiwala - Regarding your edit: Do you work with user3545187? How do you know that is the code he is using?